# Why does a new user account fix my pod install?

Tags: macos, cocoapods, crashlytics

I'm using cocoapods, and it errors every time it tries to install Crashlytics. This is the error:

```
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/3l/8_q_611x0ms5z5pk1n_79g_40000gn/T/d20160630-21289-u98pwu/file.zip https://kit-downloads.fabric.io/cocoapods/crashlytics/3.7.2/crashlytics.zip --create-dirs --netrc

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (35) SSL peer handshake failed, the server most likely requires a client certificate to connect
```

I'm using OS X 10.11.4 (15E65). So I created a brand spankin' new user account, and this same `pod install` works just fine! What might be the difference between an old and a new user account that would prevent cocoapods from working properly? Are there permissions or certificates or anything I should be comparing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ brew update
$ brew upgrade openssl
$ brew link openssl --force
$ brew install --with-openssl curl
$ brew link curl --force
```

then reload you shell profile (`source ~/.bash_profile` or `source ~/.zshrc`), confirm you curl

```
$ which curl
/usr/local/bin/curl
$ curl --version
curl 7.47.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0) libcurl/7.47.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2e zlib/1.2.5
```

finally you will good to go. :)

Comment: This finally fixed the `curl: (35) SSL peer handshake failed, the server most likely requires a client certificate to connect` Mac OS X issue for me, thank you!!! :)

Comment: doesn't work starting from `brew link openssl --force`:
`Warning: Refusing to link: openssl
Linking keg-only openssl means you may end up linking against the insecure,
deprecated system OpenSSL while using the headers from Homebrew's openssl.
Instead, pass the full include/library paths to your compiler e.g.:
  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib`

Comment: lately I ran into exact this issue, however `--with-openssl` option is no longer supported, so in my case I uninstalled `curl` and re-installed `brew install curl-openssl` instead