# Error installing Crashlytics curl: (35) SSL peer handshake failed, the server most likely requires a client certificate to connect

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

Installing Crashlytics (3.7.3)

```
[!] Error installing Crashlytics
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/2n/hv7xjs3x1mz8988vz8nl3mc40000gn/T/d20160817-1341-a6uhwh/file.zip https://kit-downloads.fabric.io/cocoapods/crashlytics/3.7.3/crashlytics.zip --create-dirs

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (35) SSL peer handshake failed, the server most likely requires a client certificate to connect
```

The previous thread posted 10 days back has been closed by some other user.

[Error installing Crashlytics - SSL peer handshake failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38761716/error-installing-crashlytics-ssl-peer-handshake-failed)

The reply is that it is working fine with other mac osX user. What to do for the current user.

Comment: This question is the same as the question you linked. Additionally a google search results in a lot of useful information. Try to use these resources before you repost a question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error installing Crashlytics - SSL peer handshake failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38761716/error-installing-crashlytics-ssl-peer-handshake-failed)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38131012/why-does-a-new-user-account-fix-my-pod-install Running the above commands in the link solved the issue